# Using switch statement with dynamic components in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-import

I am trying to use dynamic import in NextJS and I do not understand why it works only while storing imported component in a variable. It breaks when I try to return it from other function.

It works this way:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";


const Article = dynamic(() => import("tutorial/ru/welcome.mdx"));
```

but like this, well, it breaks:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

export default ({ route }) => {
  switch (route) {
    case "ru":
    default:
      return dynamic(() => import("tutorial/ru/welcome.mdx"));
  }
};
```

I get the *Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component* message.

Comment: Both those imports should result in the same value. I think your bug is somewhere else. What is the code with the hook is raising that message?

Comment: I dont have any hooks in that part of the component tree, I think there are hook in the "dynamic" implementation, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to get over this issue!

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

import Loader from "components/Loader/Loader";
import Error from "pages/_error";

export default ({ route }) => {
  const Article =  dynamic(
    () => import(`tutorial/${route}.mdx`).catch(err => {
      return () => <Error />
    }),
    { loading: () => <Loader /> }
  );
  return <Article />
};
```

I should store the component in the variable after all, but I get the component itself dynamically using literal strings, and after that I return the component as tag (). Works fine now!

Comment: Does this really work for you? It just shows the loader for me and never loads...

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Yes, it works fine. Does it says anything in the console?

Comment: After a lot of experimenting it turns out that the path in the call to import is interpreted by babel and it essentially builds a giant module for all possible modules that could be matched (in this case `tutorial/*.mdx`). They may even be duplicated if other imports overlap. In my case my path was way too expansive and it was causing OOM crashes or it was too complicated and couldn't figure out the route. The support and error handling around this area is a little confusing but it does work in straight forward cases like this.

Comment: @justin.m.chase Understood. That is an interesting situation. In my case it was broken into separate bundles.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to export it , then try to use it like so :

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";


const Article = dynamic(() => import("tutorial/ru/welcome.mdx"));

export default Article;
```

then try to use it in switch statement :

```
import Article from './Article';
export default ({ route }) => {
  switch (route) {
    case "ru":
     return (<></>)
    default:
      return <Article />;
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes, it works this way, but it won't be dynamic anymore. 

It works this way tho:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const Article = dynamic(() => import("tutorial/ru/welcome.mdx"));

export default ({ route }) => {
  switch (route) {
    case "ru":
     return (<></>)
    default:
      return <Article />;
  }
};
```

But all these variable names... it will be a mess.